# How can I access my database in xampp remotely?

Tags: mysql, netbeans, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm doing a Java project in Netbeans. I use xampp server in phpmyadmin for the database service. But each time I run the project, I have to start the xampp server. And also it is only available in my laptop. How can I configure it such that it wherever(any other computer) I run the Java application, the database gets automatically connected and data is retrieved. In the Java code, the connection is made like this:

```
Connection con = null;
        
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/food_waste","root","");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Connected");
            return con;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Make_donation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Not Connected");
            return null;
        }
```

Do I have to change anything over here as well. I'm looking for solution for a really long time. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a server where you can install database. The server can be something that you rent or some computer that you have at home that you use as a server.

You need to make sure that the database is reachable from outside (for MariaDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/).
In your connection string you need to replace "localhost" with something that is identifying your server.

If you are renting a server you can use the static IP. If you are using a computer at home as a server you will most likely have a dynamic IP. So if you want to connect from outside your home network to your database you will need something that handles the change of IPs (something like noip.com or any other dynamic DNS service). So you would need to replace "localhost" with an URL that is provided by the service you choose. And you will need to use port-forwarding if you are behind a router.